# more examples on games

Tags: algebraic-topology, game-theory

As in the example of the  game of $Hex$, it needs some tools from algebraic topology to prove that there is exactly one winner in the game

> > I wonder if there are more examples on games to be like applications of algebraic topology...

Comment: What is Hex? Please provide more background and/or links. Also you should google for "topological games" (this is a  well-established branch of game theory).

Comment: @ Martin Brandenburg, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game) I mean to use maybe some fixed point theorems such as Brouwer.

Comment: I think the statement that one needs tools from algebraic topology to prove that Hex has a unique winner is seriously misleading. What is true is that proving it is very similar to proving the Jordan curve theorem, but the result is purely combinatorial.